# Scrolling marquee text wrap on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

I am working on a scrolling marquee SharePoint web part. The web part is using the cycle plugin here (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

The text will scrolling down to the bottom and reappear at the top. It works as expected in IE8. However, in IE9, some string will have problem. (e.g. UAT Testing on 9 May) When the text reappear at the top it wrapped by unknown reason.

fiddle link here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/9PK6z/18/

See the picture below:

[image]

Here is the part of script:

```
<div id='ticker_10eb4222-addd-4f86-8d84-94926eae0aa2' class='ticker' style='position: relative; width: 530px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden;'>
<ul class="list-style1"><li><span>UAT Testing on 1 Aug</span></li></ul>
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
    for(var i =0; i<2; i++) { 
        $('#ticker_10eb4222-addd-4f86-8d84-94926eae0aa2')
        .find("ul")
        .clone()
        .appendTo($('#ticker_10eb4222-addd-4f86-8d84-94926eae0aa2')); 
    } 

    $('#ticker_10eb4222-addd-4f86-8d84-94926eae0aa2')
        .cycle({ fx: 'scrollVert', continuous: 1, speed: $('#ticker_10eb4222-addd-4f86-8d84-94926eae0aa2')
        .find("ul:eq(0) li").size() * 3000, delay: 0, easing: 'linear', rev:0 }); 
}); 

</script>
```

String like "UAT Testing at 1 Aug" will not have problem. I have tried many combination still not find the pattern.
What changes in IE9 cause the problem?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? I get an `undefined` function error

Comment: Sorry for late respond. I don't know how to let you reproduce easiler. However, I have tried several tests. If change the string to UAT Testing at 1 Aug. It will be fine. So there is something wrong with "on " pattern.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the exact fiddle but I made this one which generate the same bug on IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/7qwAr/24/

Comment: actually I found my mistake on fiddle. New link here: http://jsfiddle.net/9PK6z/18/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle it seemed to be an issue with the `overflow` css property.

I found that by switching the `overflow` from the `#ticker` element to the `ul` element, it started to work

```
.bochk-list-style1 {
    background-color:#ffffb6;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#ticker {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

I tested this in Chrome and IE9 and it seemed to work ok

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonscript/56Y9a/1/)**

Comment: Thanks! I have tried your fix but when there are mulitple <li> elements it will not work. But you give me the idea. I fix the width to 530px using css and it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark That's strange, my jsFiddle example has multiple `<li>` elements. Glad you got it working though

Comment: I browse your fiddle link directly using IE9. The string are wrapped. IE is bad anyway =(